# JSON plus spring mvc 3.2 error 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring-mvc

What did I do wrong? I try to use Spring mvc and JSON. When I try to debug my code I am looking that javascript works but doesn't works controller. In browser I get error  415 Unsupported Media Type.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#newSmartphoneForm').submit(function(event) {

      var producer = $('#producer').val();
      var model = $('#model').val();
      var price = $('#price').val();
      var json = { "producer" : producer, "model" : model, "price": price};

    $.ajax({
        url: $("#newSmartphoneForm").attr( "action"),
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        type: "POST",

        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        },
        success: function(smartphone) {
            var respContent = "";

            respContent += "<span class='success'>Smartphone was    created: [";
            respContent += smartphone.producer + " : ";
            respContent += smartphone.model + " : " ;
            respContent += smartphone.price + "]</span>";

            $("#sPhoneFromResponse").html(respContent);         
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

Controllers:

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST, 
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Smartphone createSmartphone(@RequestBody Smartphone smartphone) {
    return smartphoneService.create(smartphone);
}
```

Comment: What Spring MVC version are you using? Open up your Network console. Are you seeing the `Content-Type` header being sent? Show us your `Smartphone` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be happening because you do not have Jackson on your classpath at runtime.

The error message says that the server cannot handle your JSON request for some reason. JSON is converted to a Java object with a thing that is called *message converter*. If you have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your Spring XML config (or you have Java Config enabled), the JSON message converter is registered automatically. If you don't, you have to register it.

Comment: Alexey, you are right. Thank you. I added <mvc:annotation-driven /> and it's helped. But <mvc:annotation-driven /> there are different kinds (http://www.springframework.org/schema: cash, mvc, task). I chose http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc and all work :)

Comment: As reference for future searchers: spring mvn would produce a `415` in the same manner if `Content-Type` is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Setting to `application/json`, as the poster does, is the adequate way.