# calling a web service with multiple data using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm newer in angular js and I would like to call the web-service (implemented with Spring REST ) which use multiple data in his request body but i didn't now how the parsing can be done.  Can someone help me please ?

This is my Spring method in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addpost", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String addpost(@RequestBody PostDto post, @RequestBody UserDto user) {
        postservice.addPost(post, user);
        return "post inserted";

    }
```

This  is how i tried to call this method

```
$scope.addPost=function(x,y){

        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/wall/addpost',[x,y]).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.persons.push(data);
             $scope.user="";
             $scope.post="";
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              alert("erreur");

          })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look [**`$http`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)  API, you will find that `$http.post` second parameter contain json of object which we want to post to the server. So that could `{post: x, user: y}` & then `JSON.stringify()` that json & pass it to server. sending array in data will won't be understand by your server side method.

**Code**

```
$scope.addPost = function(x, y) {

  $http.post('http://localhost:8080/wall/addpost', {
    post: x, //assuming x is post
    user: y //assuming y is use r
  }, headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
             }).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.persons.push(data);
    $scope.user = "";
    $scope.post = "";
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("erreur");
  })
}
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: What about the parsing from the object stringified from Json to tow objects  post and users? it can be understable by jakson  parser ?

Comment: @user3765224 there is something like it, then we can do. I don't aware of  jakson parser because I'm from `.Net` background

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400

Comment: try without `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: You 1st part of code will look something like this `$http.post('http://localhost:8080/wall/addpost', {
    post: x, //assuming x is post
    user: y //assuming y is use r
  }).`

Comment: same response returned by the serve without  JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 1):

You need to send across the data using application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/wall/addpost',
    data: $.param({post: x, user: y}),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
```

See this answer for more details [How can I post data as form data instead of a request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)

Also your function definition should be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addpost", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String addpost(@RequestParam PostDto post, @RequestParam UserDto user) {
        postservice.addPost(post, user);
        return "post inserted";

    }
```

Comment: how can i do it in my case ?  @thedoctor

Comment: $ is not defined should i inject it ?

Comment: Can you load a full version of jquery before loading angularjs, the $.param comes from jquery.

Comment: i downloaaded  it the $.param work well now but still a problem HTTP code error 415 type not supported by the server

Comment: Have a look at the server logs to see if there was an exception, also see this answer to see if it's relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344352/json-plus-spring-mvc-3-2-error-415-unsupported-media-type. Also can you try and take off headers section on the annotation in your java code as you're not sending the overall request in JSON format.

Answer (score -1):

AngularJS handles `POST's` differently than what you're probably used to (jQuery for example). One thing I do, is set up a default way for app's `.config()` to handle $http requests, by defaulting headers to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and also serializing objects before a request is made.

```
angular.module('yourApp', [])

    .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

        // default header
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';

        // using transformRequest this gets handled before each $http execution

        $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function (data) {
            if (data === undefined) {
                return data;
            }

            return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' 
                ? $.param(data) // serialize it if it's an object
                : data;         // otherwise leave it alone
        };
    });
```

Now you'll be able to use it like you always do:

```
$http.post('url', { /* your data in an object */ });
```

Comment: there is an error while compiling tthis statement $.param(data) : data;

Comment: Are you passing in data as an object?

Comment: I'd padssed the data as $http.post('http://localhost:8080/wall/addpost',{post: x, user: y})

Comment: Why is there a semi-colon after your URL?

Comment: You might actually have to have jQuery included in your project, not sure if $.param is part of angularJS's jQuery-lite